# Trouble matching paint color - should I try again?

Tags: paint

I need to touch up paint in a large room. I cut a chip out of the wall and brought it to a box store, which color-matched it. I didn't watch them match it so I don't know which method they used.

The color they produced looked right when they dabbed it on the paint chip in the store, but when I went back and put it on the walls, it clearly didn't match. It was not quite the same color and looks blotchy, even after drying fully. The problem was not the sheen, but the color.

My question is: Does matching paint colors sometimes just not work, and I need to give up and repaint the whole room? Or should I try going back to the store (or maybe try a different store) and ask them to match again? Is there anything else I can do at the store to help ensure they match accurately?

Comment: i would take another sample of the old paint and a sample of the new (dry) paint .... ask them to match the old paint .... if they come up with the same match as before, then ask them to match the new paint .... if it still the same match, then go someplace else

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you'll ever get it.

Paint the entire wall where the touch up is needed, no need to paint the entire room.  If it's close, you will not notice the difference between walls nor even breaks in the wall, with mouldings, etc..

Comment: I agree. That type of matching is a fool's errand. Even if they get the color perfect, the sheen is likely to be off. Even if it's the same product, one has aged and one hasn't. paint the entire wall, or to a point where the transition is inconspicuous.